# Querying within longitude and latitude in MySQL

Tags: mysql, geolocation, geospatial, geo

Before asking for specific code examples, I just wanted to ask whether it is possible to make a query something like this pseudo code:

select items from table where lat/lon = -within x miles of a certain lat/lon point-

Is that doable? Or do I have to jump through some hoops?
Any good approaches that could be recommended would be great!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You should search for the Haversine formula, but a good start could be:

- [Creating a Store Locator with PHP, MySQL & Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3) - See Section 'Finding Locations with MySQL'
- [Geo/Spatial Search with MySQL](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL)

Citing from the first url:

*Here's the SQL statement that will find the closest 20 locations that are within a radius of 25 miles to the 37, -122 coordinate. It calculates the distance based on the latitude/longitude of that row and the target latitude/longitude, and then asks for only rows where the distance value is less than 25, orders the whole query by distance, and limits it to 20 results. To search by kilometers instead of miles, replace 3959 with 6371.*

```
SELECT
    id,
    ( 3959
      * acos( cos( radians(37) )
              * cos(  radians( lat )   )
              * cos(  radians( lng ) - radians(-122) )
            + sin( radians(37) )
              * sin( radians( lat ) )
            )
    )
    AS distance
FROM markers
HAVING distance < 25
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I just posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697624/querying-for-things-near-a-geolocation

Comment: This doesn't return any calculated distance for me, just `NULL` the whole time.

Comment: Not returning results on exact point. These results returning distance as NULL that not works on having clause.

Comment: 37 = lng and -12=lat, as proposed by conventional essays?:)

Comment: @DavidYell didn't understand why it returns `NULL` in your case. I've used it three years ago and today, and it actually perfetly works.

Comment: @Maykonn didn't understand why it returns `NULL` in your case. I've used it three years ago and today, and it actually perfetly works.

Answer (score 7):

I would highly recommend using either SpatiaLite or PostGIS for this kind of operation. They have built in the kind of functions you are trying to hand code. They also have proper support for spatial data which doesn't really exist in MySQL.

Not exactly a solution in MySQL but a better solution if you want to keep doing spatial requests in the future.