# How can I get all points within a given range based on its latitude and longitude?

Tags: php, mysql, math, mysqli

scenario: I have a db with three tables, users, locations, stock;

within users I have: `id, name, email`

within locations I have: `id, place, lati, logi`

within stock I have: `id, user_id, product, total_count, location_id`

I am fairly new and I managed to join all the tables:

```
$qry = "
SELECT COUNT(id)
  FROM stock
  LEFT
  JOIN users 
   ON stock.user_id= users.id
  LEFT
  JOIN locations
   ON stock.location_id= locations.id ";
```

But what I am hoping to be able to do is sort it by distance using the lati and logi. So for example, I want everything within 25 miles, sorted closest to furthest.

How can i pull this off giving the scenario?

I did some googling but everything i'm finding show me how I can get the distance between two points, but what I want to be able to use one set of points, and get everything within X miles of it?

Not sure if that all makes sense ?

Comment: What is the formula for calculating the distance between two points of latitude and longitude?

Comment: you have to apple sin and cos function for this.

Comment: Is the Haversine formula (as per http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) okay?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994718/mysql-longitude-and-latitude-query-for-other-rows-within-x-mile-radius

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687312/querying-within-longitude-and-latitude-in-mysql

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12269/Distance-between-locations-using-latitude-and-long its for sql-server but the concept is just the same. Create the function for mysql and use it your query

Comment: I guess I might have just been overthinking it. Thanks @devpro the link you provided was able to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with below simplified formula for calculating this in my application :

`pow(CentralLati - LatitudeofCircle, 2)   + 
pow(CentralLongi - LongitudeofCircle, 2) <= 4`

where,

CentralLati , CentralLongi => co-ordinates of a point A

LatitudeofCircle, LongitudeofCircle => co-ordinates of the points 25kms around the point A.

You may adjust the above formula to match your database naming conventions.

Hope I understood your requirement correctly.